# PF5.3 Atmosphere2.4 Glass fish exception:Request is within the scope of a filter or servlet that does not support asynchronous operations

Tags: jsf, primefaces, glassfish, atmosphere

I have the following serious problem:

Glass Fish Exception:

> Request is within the scope of a filter or servlet that does not
>   support asynchronous operations

Running version :GLASSFISH4.1.1    PRIMEFACES5.3   ATMOSPHERE2.4

```
@PushEndpoint("/dzsfYjs/{userName}")
@Singleton
public class PmsDzsfYjsResource {


    @OnMessage(encoders = JSONEncoder.class)
    public String onMessage(String message) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        return URLEncoder.encode(message,"UTF-8");
    }
```

send code:

```
EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();
    eventBus.publish("/mdkp/"+this.getSelect().getGroupEn(),"hello");
```

WEB.XML config:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
           <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterCacheClass</param-name>
           <param-value>org.atmosphere.cache.UUIDBroadcasterCache</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.annotation.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.primefaces.push</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.kildeen.ref</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

exception:

```
[2015-11-29T23:10:00.615+0800] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1448809800615] [levelValue: 800] [[
  2015-11-29 23:10:00.615 [http-listener-1(1)] ERROR o.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - AtmosphereFramework exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request is within the scope of a filter or servlet that does not support asynchronous operations

[2015-11-29T23:10:00.615+0800] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(1)] [timeMillis: 1448809800615] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[Push Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Push Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request is within the scope of a filter or servlet that does not support asynchronous operations
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.startAsync(Request.java:4252)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.startAsync(Request.java:4229)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.startAsync(RequestFacade.java:1044)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.startAsync(ServletRequestWrapper.java:464)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereRequestImpl.startAsync(AtmosphereRequestImpl.java:615)
    at org.atmosphere.container.Servlet30CometSupport.suspend(Servlet30CometSupport.java:95)
    at org.atmosphere.container.Servlet30CometSupport.service(Servlet30CometSupport.java:70)
    at org.atmosphere.container.GlassFishServ30WebSocketSupport.service(GlassFishServ30WebSocketSupport.java:73)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport(AtmosphereFramework.java:2281)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.doPost(AtmosphereServlet.java:190)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.doGet(AtmosphereServlet.java:176)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.servlet.impl.event.EventBridgeFilter.doFilter(EventBridgeFilter.java:59)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.servlet.impl.produce.RequestResponseHolderFilter.doFilter(RequestResponseHolderFilter.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:122)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]

[2015-11-29T23:10:00.655+0800] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=30 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1448809800655] [levelValue: 800] [[
  2015-11-29 23:10:00.655 [http-listener-1(3)] WARN  o.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster - Duplicate resource 06d28e82-2379-4fbe-a07e-fbd07f4fe8e8. Could be caused by a dead connection not detected by your server. Replacing the old one with the fresh one]]

[2015-11-29T23:10:00.656+0800] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=30 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1448809800656] [levelValue: 800] [[
  2015-11-29 23:10:00.656 [http-listener-1(3)] ERROR o.a.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor - Interceptor Atmosphere LifeCycle crashed. Processing will continue with other interceptor.
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to javax.servlet.AsyncContext
    at org.atmosphere.container.Servlet30CometSupport.endAsyncContext(Servlet30CometSupport.java:124) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.atmosphere.container.Servlet30CometSupport.complete(Servlet30CometSupport.java:119) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.atmosphere.container.Servlet30CometSupport.complete(Servlet30CometSupport.java:46) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResourceImpl.cancel(AtmosphereResourceImpl.java:806) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResourceImpl.dirtyClose(AtmosphereResourceImpl.java:910) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster.addAtmosphereResource(DefaultBroadcaster.java:1370) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereResourceImpl.suspend(AtmosphereResourceImpl.java:401) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.atmosphere.interceptor.AtmosphereResourceLifecycleInterceptor.postInspect(AtmosphereResourceLifecycleInterceptor.java:145) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.postInterceptors(AsynchronousProcessor.java:374) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.action(AsynchronousProcessor.java:230) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.suspended(AsynchronousProcessor.java:115) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.atmosphere.container.Servlet30CometSupport.service(Servlet30CometSupport.java:68) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.atmosphere.container.GlassFishServ30WebSocketSupport.service(GlassFishServ30WebSocketSupport.java:73) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport(AtmosphereFramework.java:2281) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.doPost(AtmosphereServlet.java:190) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.doGet(AtmosphereServlet.java:176) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [javax.servlet-api.jar:3.1.0]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [javax.servlet-api.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:305) [tyrus-container-servlet.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.deltaspike.servlet.impl.event.EventBridgeFilter.doFilter(EventBridgeFilter.java:59) [deltaspike-servlet-module-impl-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.deltaspike.servlet.impl.produce.RequestResponseHolderFilter.doFilter(RequestResponseHolderFilter.java:63) [deltaspike-servlet-module-impl-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.omnifaces.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:122) [omnifaces-2.1.jar:2.1]
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108) [omnifaces-2.1.jar:2.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673) [web-core.jar:na]
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99) [web-glue.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283) [web-core.jar:na]
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459) [kernel.jar:na]
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167) [kernel.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_66]]]

[2015-11-29T23:10:00.657+0800] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=30 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1448809800657] [levelValue: 800] [[
  2015-11-29 23:10:00.657 [http-listener-1(3)] ERROR o.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - AtmosphereFramework exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request is within the scope of a filter or servlet that does not support asynchronous operations
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.startAsync(Request.java:4252) ~[web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.startAsync(Request.java:4229) ~[web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.startAsync(RequestFacade.java:1044) ~[web-core.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.startAsync(ServletRequestWrapper.java:464) ~[javax.servlet-api.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereRequestImpl.startAsync(AtmosphereRequestImpl.java:615) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.atmosphere.container.Servlet30CometSupport.suspend(Servlet30CometSupport.java:95) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.atmosphere.container.Servlet30CometSupport.service(Servlet30CometSupport.java:70) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.atmosphere.container.GlassFishServ30WebSocketSupport.service(GlassFishServ30WebSocketSupport.java:73) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport(AtmosphereFramework.java:2281) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.doPost(AtmosphereServlet.java:190) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.doGet(AtmosphereServlet.java:176) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [javax.servlet-api.jar:3.1.0]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [javax.servlet-api.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:305) [tyrus-container-servlet.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.deltaspike.servlet.impl.event.EventBridgeFilter.doFilter(EventBridgeFilter.java:59) [deltaspike-servlet-module-impl-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.deltaspike.servlet.impl.produce.RequestResponseHolderFilter.doFilter(RequestResponseHolderFilter.java:63) [deltaspike-servlet-module-impl-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383) [shiro-core-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125) [shiro-web-1.2.3.jar:1.2.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.omnifaces.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:122) [omnifaces-2.1.jar:2.1]
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108) [omnifaces-2.1.jar:2.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673) [web-core.jar:na]
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99) [web-glue.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416) [web-core.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283) [web-core.jar:na]
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459) [kernel.jar:na]
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167) [kernel.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_66]]]
```

Is not very stable, often appear these exceptions, which leads to the users cannot use.

Answer (score 3):

> Request is within the scope of a filter or servlet that does not
>   support asynchronous operations

This means that the Servlet or Filter mapped to the request is not supporting asynchronous operations. I can see that `<async-supported>true</async-supported>` is already added to `PushServlet`. Make sure that you add async support to the filters as well.

Looking at the stacktrace, seems like you are using `CharacterEncodingFilter` from omnifaces library which is, ideally, mapped to all incoming requests. This might be causing the issue. Add async support to this filter.

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.omnifaces.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
   <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Hello, could you please tell me whether each filter is added < async - supported > true < / async - supported > ?

Comment: Add it to all the filters that is mapped to `/*` pattern. Better to post your whole web.xml so that I can refer to them in my answer.

Comment: Because I have < filter - name > FileUploadFilter < / filter - name >, < the filter - class > org. Omnifaces. Filter. GzipResponseFilter < / filter - class >, < the filter - class > org.. Apache shiro. Web. Servlet. ShiroFilter < / filter - class >

Comment: Yes, please add async-support to all those filters and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: Hello, I added after completion, the system becomes very unstable, often asynchronous exceptions

Comment: _the system becomes very unstable_ - what do you mean? Are you getting the same exception? Also, please edit your question and post the whole web.xml.